# Stripe's fees on the application side with a subscription, trying to make an update on the invoice but its too fast

Tags: php, stripe-payments, webhooks

I'm creating a stripe subscription with the following code:

```
$subscription = $stripe->subscriptions->create([
        'customer' => {{CUSTOMER ID}},
        'items' => [
            [
                'price' => $price->id,
                'quantity' => $quantity,
            ],
        ],
        'default_source' => $card,
        'billing_cycle_anchor'=> $time,
        'proration_behavior' => 'create_prorations',
        'transfer_data' => [
            'destination'=>{{DESTINATION ID}}
        ]
    ]);
```

Everything works out fine, but there is an issue. The fees fall on the platform's side and here's the dilemma through a realistic outcome:

Customer is charged 0.40 cents. Stripe's fee is 2.9% + 30 cents  (.31 cents) and the platform we operate takes 2.5% (.01 cents). As the fee falls on us as the platform, we don't have the money because of the percentage we take. So the solution is to "charge" the connected account for both our take and the credit card processing fee (meaning 2.5% + 2.9% + 30 cents).

The issue here is that we can't use the `application_fee_percent` because that's purely a percentage (it will ignore the 30 cents - plus this can't be calculated from a percentage basis because prorations are enabled).

I have tried listening to the webhook of `invoice.created` so that I can calculate the `application_fee_amount` dynamically but it says "Cannot change finalized invoice." So the question becomes, what's the proper flow here? What am I missing to fix this issue we're having?

Answer (score 0):

Invoices created for less than the minimum amount for the currency do not actually make a charge, and instead just affect the Customer Balance: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/customer/balance#examples

Comment: Ok, but I’m not sure how this relates to calculating the application fee for a connected account and implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out.

As per the documentation here: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/invoices/subscription

This explains that the first invoice on creating the subscription is created and finalized immediately (you cannot change it), while the next invoice in the billing cycle sits in "draft" for an hour. During that time, you can modify that invoice however you please during that hour. This means I have to figure out a different approach to gathering fees.